# Mammals instinctively lick their wounds. There are benefits and risks. If your immune system is healthy, is it wise to lick your wounds?

Tags: risks, first-aid, wound-care, wound, saliva

Wikipedia [writes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wound_licking):

> Wound licking is an instinctive response in humans and many other animals to lick an injury. Dogs, cats, small rodents and primates all lick wounds.[1] Saliva contains tissue factor which promotes the blood clotting mechanism. The enzyme lysozyme is found in many tissues and is known to attack the cell walls of many gram-positive bacteria, aiding in defense against infection. ... However, there are also infection risks due to bacteria in the human mouth.

OK. So humans instinctively lick cuts and other wounds, and this carries both benefits and [risks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wound_licking#Risks_2).

In a healthy person with a healthy immune system, do the benefits generally outweigh the risks?